# Django/Selenium KeyError from None 'GMAIL_PASSWORD'

Tags: django, selenium, testing

```
    ERROR: test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in (functional_tests.test_login.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../Django/python-tdd-book/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 36, in test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in
    body = self.wait_for_email(test_email, SUBJECT)
  File ".../Django/python-tdd-book/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 72, in wait_for_email
    inbox.pass_(os.environ['GMAIL_PASSWORD'])
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'GMAIL_PASSWORD'
```

I'm following the obeythetestinggoat book which is awesome but I can't get passed this error, I found another unresolved question on here exactly the same but, not resolved, I've tried digging into gmail access docs eg. 'Allow insecure apps', triple checking I've got the env vars loaded, the system is actually working i.e. sending emails out with the correct information and allowing login for that user when clicked, all are working except the tests, the env vars are loaded in the shell i am executing the test from ie. echo $GMAIL_PASSWORD, I did notice that the python version for this states is the system python3 but when I run which python3 from my virtualenv it shows the virtualenv version, I've tried recreating my virtualenv even, any help would be awesome I've spent a day on this error.

```
from django.core import mail 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import re
import os 
import time 
import poplib 


def wait_for_email(self, test_email, subject):
    if not self.staging_server:
        email = mail.outbox[0]
        self.assertIn(test_email, email.to)
        self.assertEqual(email.subject, subject)
        return email.body

    email_id = None
    start = time.time()
    inbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.gmail.com')
    try:
        inbox.user(test_email)
        inbox.pass_(os.environ['GMAIL_PASSWORD'])
        while time.time() - start < 60:
            # get 10 newest messages
            count, _ = inbox.stat()
            for i in reversed(range(max(1, count - 10), count + 1)):
                print('getting msg', i)
                _, lines, __ = inbox.retr(i)
                lines = [l.decode('utf8') for l in lines]
                print(lines)
                if f'Subject: {subject}' in lines:
                    email_id = i
                    body = '\n'.join(lines)
                    return body
            time.sleep(10)
    finally:
        if email_id:
            inbox.dele(email_id)
        inbox.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `os.environ['GMAIL_PASSWORD']` is raising a `KeyError` that means that the `GMAIL_PASSWORD` environment variable is not set in the current environment.

- double-check your shell environment variables.  The `env` command lists all env vars.  Check for typos, uppercase/lowercase, etc.
- less likely, but you could also check your python script -- could anything be deleting things from the environment, with `del os.environ[...]` ?

Comment: Hey thanks again Harry, the env command did it, the password wasn't listed there so wasn't loading the env vars, i switched to python-dotenv and it worked.